A TV show episode named "Die"
A few years ago, probably in 2012 or 2013, I saw the very beginning of an episode of a show. I don't know the name of the show, or what it's about, or even its genre. I know the name of the episode, "Die", but it's not a very searchable one.
It starts with a man and a boy sitting at a table. The man mutters something like "It's a bad idea" or "I shouldn't do it" and asks the boy to roll a die. The boy rolls 3 and asks what it was about. The man refuses to answer and tells the boy to go to sleep. A little later, the boy watches from his room as the man puts three bulltes into a revolver's cylinder, rolls the cylinder, puts the barrel to his head and pulls the trigger. Title card.
The show was originally in English. That is, I saw it in a translation, but the title card was in English.
I had the impression that it was shot with a digital camera, so it must be a relatively recent one.
Does anybody recognize it?

And you're sure you're not looking for a movie? Cause I think this might be Die from 2010.

@Walt Well, I guess it's possible. I'll try to check this movie later.

@Walt Yes, that was it. Thank you. If you post it as an answer, I'll accept it.

This is called Die, but it's a movie from 2010.

Six strangers awake in a cell in an underground facility. In flashbacks, their lives are exposed and in common, they are destroyed by their acts. Mark Murdock is a nihilist detective that does not have any hope in his career. Lisa Meridian is an addicted gambler that has destroyed her marriage. Robert Moretti is a self-destructive millionaire that tried to commit suicide. Melody Chambers is a young prostitute addicted in drugs. Zach Emmett is a psychiatrist that has been suffering for two years for a fatal wrong prescription to a patient. Diane Robinson is a nurse that lost her two year-old child and tried to commit suicide. Soon they learn that they have been abducted by the disturbed Jacob Odessa, who saw his father committing suicide when he was a boy. Jacob forces each prisoner to toss a dice in a deadly game of Russian roulette against another participant in a sort of trial. The survivors would have a chance to reborn in a new existence.

I'm pretty sure it includes the scene with the man and the boy that you described. Here's the trailer:



